# Print content of priority queue

Tags: java, queue, priority-queue

How do I make the print_queue work properly in Java? This is my own implementation of a queue.

**Using `Iterator()` works fine, except it prints numbers in random order.**

```
package data_structures_java ;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.PriorityQueue ;
import java.util.* ;
public class Queue_implementation {
 
    PriorityQueue<Integer> actual_queue ;
    
    public Queue_implementation(){
        actual_queue = new PriorityQueue<Integer>() ;
        
    }
    
    public  void add(int num){
        actual_queue.add(num) ;
    }
    
    public int remove(){
          return actual_queue.remove() ;          
    }
    
    public int peek(){
        if( actual_queue.isEmpty()) return -1 ;
        else return actual_queue.peek() ;
    }
    
    public int element(){
        return actual_queue.element() ;
    }
    
    public void print_queue(){      
        PriorityQueue<Integer>copy = new PriorityQueue<Integer>();
        copy.addAll(actual_queue) ;        
        Iterator<Integer> through = actual_queue.iterator() ;
        while(through.hasNext() ) {
                System.out.print(through.next() + " ") ;
        }
        System.out.println() ;
                
        actual_queue.addAll(copy) ;
        
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {            
        Queue_implementation x = new Queue_implementation() ;
        x.add(10) ;
        x.add(9) ;
        x.add(8) ;
        x.add(7) ;
        x.add(6) ;
        x.print_queue() ;
    }

}
```

I tried to use `toArray()` but it returns `Object[]`, which I don't know how to traverse:

```
Object[] queue_object_array = x.toArray() ;
Arrays.sort(queue_object_array) ;
```

Comment: Is your Queue supposed to be a Queue or is is supposed to be a PriorityQueue? They do two different things.

Comment: @WillNewton, just queue actually , but i m using std.priority queue from java api

Answer (score 10):

> Using Iterator() works fine, except it prints numbers in random order.

That's exactly what it says it will do in the Javadoc. The only way to get the ordering in the `PriorityQueue` is to use the `poll()` or `remove()` methods.

Comment: yes i dont' see the reason why he did it - me, topic starter gives you +1

Comment: ejp, but when i use remove() - i delete elements from the queue itself, do i need to store it somehow and copy back after remove()?

Comment: @ERJAN Yes, if you need the contents afterwards.

Answer (score 8):

One line solution: it is useful when you need to fast debug.

```
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(priorityQueue.toArray()));
```

Edit: Another concise code:

```
System.out.println(priorityQueue);
```

Comment: what is the difference between the code and `System.out.println(priorityQueue)`

Comment: @ZhaoGang thanks for the note. Actually it is the same after I checked. It just because my thinking process causes me to do so :D You can add a new answer, or I will edit my answer.

Comment: They are much the same, so no need for a new answer I think, please edit your answer if you would like to, thx.

Comment: @user207421 I don't say this method will print in order. It's useful for debugging. I am lazy to check but I remember the original post just wants to print out the content.

Comment: This does not print the PQ in priority order. Please read the question. Printing in order is what the question is about. *Ergo* you haven't answered it. Being too lazy to check is no excuse. I did.

Answer (score 2):

If you need to print content of priorityQueue where each element is a 2D array you can try using:

```
System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(priorityQueue.toArray());
```

If it's a 1D array:

```
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(priorityQueue.toArray());
```

Comment: This does not print the PQ in priority order. Please read the question.