# PriorityQueue sorted but the two biggest

Tags: java, collections, priority-queue, comparable

```
public class Pair implements Comparable<Pair>{
    public String name;
    public int number;

    public int compareTo(Pair other) {
        if (other == null) {
            return 1;
        }
        return Integer.compare(number, other.number);
    }
}
```

```
ht = new Hashtable<String, Pair>(perLen);
PriorityQueue<Pair> pq = new PriorityQueue<Pair>(k);
set = ht.keySet();
for (String i: set) {
        tmp0 = ht.get(i);
        if (tmp0.compareTo(pq.peek()) > 0) {
            if (pq.size() == k) {
                pq.remove();
            }
            pq.add(tmp0);
        }
}
System.out.println(pq.toString());
```

OUTPUT:

```
[OSCAR 822, ALBERTO 827, DAVID 1523, JAVIER 943]
```

I am looking for the k biggest Pairs (their number) in the hashtable and those on the output are in fact the correct ones. My question is, why are the last two swapped?

Comment: What type is pq and where is it created?

Comment: @tgdavies updated the code, sorry

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`PriorityQueue`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/PriorityQueue.html) only returns the lowest element from its head. It doesn't sort all the elements, so if you traverse the queue with `pq.toString()`, elements may not appear in order. This happens because, internally, `PriorityQueue.toString()` uses the `PriorityQueue.iterator()` method and, according to the docs:

> The Iterator provided in method `iterator()` is *not* guaranteed to traverse the elements of the priority queue in any particular order. If you need ordered traversal, consider using `Arrays.sort(pq.toArray())`.

If you want to print the elements of the priority queue in order, you should change this code:

```
System.out.println(pq.toString());
```

To the following:

```
while (!pq.isEmpty()) 
    System.out.println(pq.remove());
```

Answer (score 1):

The toString() method of the PriorityQueue class does not guarantee you the order of the elements as it uses an iterator.

Answer (score 0):

You can check the order using poll method as here:

[Print content of priority queue[java]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22928255/print-content-of-priority-queuejava)